# How Apache projects generate their dependency convergence report

Tags: dependencies

I just notice many Apache project has a very handy report called "dependency convergence report" . e.g. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/dependency-convergence.html

I just wonder which tool could be used to generated such report since I want it in my project as well. Is it a home-made tool by Apache, or Sonar plugin?

If anyone know it , please kindly inform